# Redirect user with htaccess fails

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, server

I have a WordPress website with two languages: German and English. My goal: If the browser language is English, I want the user to be redirected to the English version. I have tried to solve this with htaccess, but I get a browser error message.

My full htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

#Redirect to English page if browser language is English
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (en) [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.mywebsite.de/?lang=en [R,L]
```

When I want to visit http://www.mywebsite.de, Firefox where the language is set to English gives me the following error message:

> The website you entered redirects the request so that it can never be
>   completed.

(This is a translation from German to English.)

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: every time the page is called, the loop in the bottom two lines of your htaccess is running forever, what you want to do is qualify that you follow the `HTTP: Accept-Language` *AND* if `lang` has not been defined. This is I think why people (wikipedia) often have subdomains for languages so that they simply redirect to subdomain = `HTTP: Accept-language`

Comment: what would the solution in htaccess look like?

Comment: If I knew that I would put an answer, but Starkeen's answer looks like it could be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RewriteCond to prevent the loop error.

```
#Redirect to English page if browser language is English
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (en) [NC]
#Skip the Rule and stop the redirection, If we are already on /?lang=en
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule .* http://www.mywebsite.de/?lang=en [R,L]
```